# Python truncate function isnt working as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, truncate

I'm a bit confused about the truncate function in python. Shouldn't the truncate function empty the file and display only the second line of input? But in my file, both the first and second input line is in the file after the program ends.

Expected output in file

```
Line2 input
```

Current output in file

```
Line1 input Line2 input
```

This is what I get in file if I use .truncate(0)

[image]

```
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

print(f"Erasing the file {filename}")

print("Opening the file...")
# This empties and overrides the file when opening in w mode use 'a' to append to file
target = open(filename, 'w')

line = input("Input a line")

target.write(line)

print("Truncating ie erasing the file...")
target.truncate()

line2 = input("Input another line")

target.write(line2)

target.close()
```

Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate. See answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26917275/7977464

Comment: Try `truncate(0)`.

Comment: `truncate()` deleted the content of the files after the current cursor position (after the first line). It actually does nothing since the cursor is on the end of the file.

Comment: Tried what you guys said. Please check edit part on the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/io.html#io.IOBase.truncate), emphasis mine:

> Resize the stream to the given size in bytes **(or the current position if size is not specified)**. The current stream position isn’t changed.

You'll need to call `.truncate(0)` to truncate the file to zero bytes.

Comment: Tried what you said.Please check edit part on the question.

Comment: You will need to also `.seek(0)` if you want to rewind the file to the start.